# Headless standalone firefox never returns from making a screenshot

Tags: firefox, headless

I'm trying to make a screensot with firefox on "Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS"

```
wget -O firefox-58.0.tar.bz2 https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/58.0/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-58.0.tar.bz2
tar xvjf firefox-58.0.tar.bz2
./firefox/firefox -screenshot /tmp/test.jpg www.google.de
```

but the command never ends

the only output i get is

```
*** You are running in headless mode.

(firefox:7679): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.


(firefox:7679): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.


(firefox:7679): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.


(firefox:7679): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.


(firefox:7679): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.


(firefox:7679): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.


(firefox:7679): GConf-WARNING **: Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon:
//bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47936584/what-does-client-failed-to-connect-to-the-d-bus-daemon-mean